# Date function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am completely stuck with this problem I'm having with excel. 
Basically I am creating an computer inventory.

I have the date purchased (ex 10/5/06), and I need to know the amount of time since then (updating with todays date)

For example 10/26/06 was 5 years ago.

Is there a way to do that with the `TODAY()` function?

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, and thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your purchase date was in A1 then in B1 you could try

=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"y")&" years "&DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"ym")&" months & DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"md") & " days"

which gives "4 years 11 months 29 days"

For a useful reference on the undocumented DATEDIF see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would try DATEDIF( earlydate, laterdate, "d" ) <- "d" for Days. Try "m", "y", etc.

So if the first date was in A1

```
=DATEDIF($A1,NOW(),"d")
```

Comment: DATEDIFF is a VBA function, it is not an Excel function.